# Elastic effect on UISlider on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uislider

I have four points on `UISlider` at **0, 1, 2 and 3**. I want that when thumb position is from 0-1, it should come back to 0 but with elastic effect. Similar for 1-2, 2-3. This implementation will give me an edge in my application.

I have tried it with no elastic effect. But it does not look good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell your slider to send an action on the “Touch Up Inside” event (`UIControlEventTouchUpInside`).  Hook the action up to this method:

```
- (IBAction)dragEndedWithSlider:(UISlider *)sender {
    CGFloat roundedValue = roundf(sender.value);
    [sender setValue:roundedValue animated:YES];
}
```

You can use `truncf` instead of `roundf` if that's what you really want.

Comment: Hi @rob mayoff, Could u say me i have a scale like 1-2-3-4-5...now the thumb image should be moving to 2-4 only and and after 4 it shouldn't move further.

Answer (score 2):

Bind this method to slider Value Changed in Interface builder

```
   -(IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender {

        slider.value = (int)slider.value;
    }
```

Comment: Hi NeverBe, Could u say me i have a scale like 1-2-3-4-5...now the thumb image should be moving to 2-4 only and and after 4 it shouldn't move further.

Answer (score 2):

You could subclass UISlider and add this:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    CGFloat floorValue = floor(self.value);

    if ((self.value - floorValue) > 0.5) {

        [self setValue: floorValue + 1.0 animated: YES];

    } else {

        [self setValue: floorValue animated: YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi rokjarc, Could u say me i have a scale like 1-2-3-4-5...now the thumb image should be moving to 2-4 only and and after 4 it shouldn't move further.

Comment: @sailaja: it's hard to put code in the comment (and editing answer to other question is a no-go). In your case i'd override `touchesMoved:`. There you can enforce minimum and maximum slider offset. Something like  `if (self.value < 2.0) [self setValue: 2.0]; else if (self.value > 4.0) [self setValue 4.0];`